# Is there a module or tool within ServiceNow to organize debt of repetitive tasks requested in the Service Catalog?

Tags: process, request, servicenow

At my enterprise, we utilize Problem Management to eliminate recurring incidents of course - but how do we organize efforts to eliminate recurring requests?

We are trying to minimize debt by shifting some work to cheaper teams or even outside of IT, consider changing the framework of our applications in order save money in the long run by adding a feature to let the users update things on their own, or even weigh the pros and cons of building out automation to replace manual labor. It would be great if we could tie all of the Service Request or Catalog Tasks together similar to a Problem record - and provide a place for us to organize our efforts or progress made.

Does anyone have any solutions to this? How do you organize your requests?

One solution was to just use Problem and classify them differently - but the cons are that Problem doesn't include Requests in ITIL. Another idea was to build another module that functioned similarly to Problem, but had its own fields and name. We would love to organize this directly in ServiceNow - and would like to have more functionality that PA Dashboards can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The orchestration plugin/module comes with an ROI app which helps you calculate and report on the amount of time/man hours/dollars you are saving with your automation efforts. It basically just tracks tasks and assigns a monetary value based on the salary or wage of the performer that usually executes the task.